# How to use gsub for the given the scenario in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am giving the values as:

```
str = 'test["test1", "test2"]'
```

Using `gsub`, I want the value as `'["test1", "test2"]'`.

The condition is, the values before and after braces `[` / `]` should be removed.

Comment: FYI: `str[/\[.*\]/]` would return the `[...]` part which seems easier than replacing the inverse via `gsub`.

Answer (score 3):

This should remove anything before and after `[` and `]`:

```rb
str.gsub(/^[^\[]+/, '').gsub(/[^\]]+$/, '')
```

By parts:

```rb
> str = 'test["test`", "test2"]test'
 => "test[\"test`\", \"test2\"]test" 
> str.gsub(/^[^\[]+/, '')
 => "[\"test`\", \"test2\"]test" 
> str.gsub(/[^\]]+$/, '')
 => "test[\"test`\", \"test2\"]" 
> str.gsub(/^[^\[]+/, '').gsub(/[^\]]+$/, '')
 => "[\"test`\", \"test2\"]"
```